# How do I make a horizontal centered navbar that doesn't stretch the whole page?

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I've been wanting to make a horizontal navbar that doesn't stretch the whole page. Ended up following a tutorial on how to make a navbar that is really similar to what I have in mind (https://cssdeck.com/blog/super-simple-horizontal-navigation-bar/), the only problem is that it isn't centered and the background matches the whole page in width, which I don't want.I uploaded a sketch image of how I want the navbar to appear.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mCTm.png)

The code on the site is as follows:

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; }
```

I tried creating a div which encapsulates the unordered list, made its width 40% of the page, centered it using margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto. Then I specified each list item to be 25% of the parent element (which is the div since I didn't specify width for the unordered list element itself), as I want 4 list items to be on the navbar (100/4 = 25). And so, I hope that by making some changes to the tutorial code I found online, I can learn how to modify my own code.

Really hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some CSS changes which will solve your issue:

```css
#nav {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  display: table;
  }
#nav li {
  float: left; }
#nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #069;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c00;
  background-color: #fff; }
#nav li:last-child a{border: none;}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, this is actually perfect! Thank you so much. Now, if I were to want to change the width of the navbar, where I should make modifications to? To make it a tad bigger or smaller.

Comment: As you add or remove links, it will remain in the center.

Comment: Ok, understood!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Adjust spacing, colors, etc as you like:

```
/* make navbar full-width, but center items inside */
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
/* display <li>'s inlin, give all a right border */
#nav li {
  display:inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/* add a left border to the first <li> */
#nav li:first-child { border-left: 1px solid #ccc }

/* make <a> fill the full <li> space, set padding, text-decoration, etc */
#nav li a { display: block; padding: 0.5rem 1rem }

/* Optional...hover */
#nav li a:hover {
   background:#bbb;
   color: white;
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jefs42/6hd5obev/15/